# MySQL - reformat a column value dependant on existing value

Tags: mysql

Am needing to provide a concatenated field from a select query which is dependant on existing values.

```
SELECT `delegate`.`FirstName` AS `First Name`,
   `delegate`.`LastName` AS `Last Name`,
   `organisation`.`Name` AS `Organisation`,
    IF (`delegate`.`PhoneWork`  IS NOT NULL, 'Yes','No') AS `WorkPhone`),
   `delegate`.`EmailAddress` AS `Email Address`
FROM `delegate`
JOIN `organisation` on((`delegate`.`OrganisationID` = `organisation`.`ID`))
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: what is the error whats not working can you elaborate it with some more brief in your question ?

Comment: Thanks heaps for responding Khalid
- Workphone needs to be a concatentation of Area code 
  and Phone number, but blank if there is no phone    number or area code. It seems to be the IF statement I'm not getting

Comment: Just let us know if you need more!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Mysql you can use `CONCAT` function to concatenate values ,you can use your logic in `if()` to show yes/no according to the criteria.if you want to show the value from column when its not empty then replace 'Yes' with your column name

```
SELECT 
   `d`.`FirstName` AS `First Name`,
   `d`.`LastName` AS `Last Name`,
   `o`.`Name` AS `Organisation`,
    IF (`d`.`PhoneWork`  IS NOT NULL AND `d`.areacode IS NOT NULL,CONCAT(`d`.`PhoneWork`,' ',`d`.areacode),'your value') AS `concat_colum`,
    IF (`d`.`PhoneWork`  IS NOT NULL,'Yes','No') AS `WorkPhone`,
    IF (`d`.`areacode`  IS NOT NULL,'Yes','No') AS `areacode`,
   `d`.`EmailAddress` AS `Email Address`,
FROM `delegate` d
JOIN `organisation` o ON(`d`.`OrganisationID` = `o`.`ID`)
```

You can do the same by using `CASE` too

```
SELECT 
   `d`.`FirstName` AS `First Name`,
   `d`.`LastName` AS `Last Name`,
   `o`.`Name` AS `Organisation`,
    CASE WHEN 
    `d`.`PhoneWork`  IS NOT NULL AND `d`.areacode IS NOT NULL
    THEN CONCAT(`d`.`PhoneWork`,' ',`d`.areacode)
    ELSE 'your value' END  AS `concat_colum`,
    CASE WHEN `d`.`PhoneWork`  IS NOT NULL THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS `WorkPhone`,
    CASE WHEN `d`.`areacode`  IS NOT NULL THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END  AS `areacode`,    
   `d`.`EmailAddress` AS `Email Address`,
FROM `delegate` d
JOIN `organisation` o ON(`d`.`OrganisationID` = `o`.`ID`)
```

Comment: @Kahlid -- appreciate your very clear answer!